# Definition of a range in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Enderton's 'Elements of Set Theory' and he makes this claim:

The set $ \bigcup \{\ y\mid(x,y) \in F\} $  is equal to F(x) whenever F is a function and x $\in$ dom F.

Question: why isn't $\{\ y\mid(x,y) \in F\} $ enough for this equality? Why do we need arbitrary union? Why doesn't that set define the range of F without arbitrary union?

Comment: So what’s Enderton’s definition of $F(x)$ for a map $F$ and $x ∈ \operatorname{dom} F$?

Comment: I use: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113296/operatornamefuncf-tox-y-in-f-to-fx-y-and-operatornamefuncf-t

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be the unique map $\{a\}\to\{b\}$. Then for $x=a$, we have $\{\,y\mid (x,y)\in F\,\}=\{b\}$, but $F(a)=b$, not $\{b\}$. As $\bigcup\{b\}=b$, Enderton is correct.