# to prove: $(A, \bot)$ is Magma $\to \forall x,y \in A:\big ((x \bot y) \in A \big ) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> **Definition**: Magma is a couple $(A, \bot)$ with $\bot: (A \times A) \to A$

$\bot: (A \times A) \to A$ for $ \begin{cases} \bot \text{ is relation} \\ \forall x,y,z : \big ((x,y) \in \bot \wedge (x,z) \in \bot \to y=z) \big )  \\ \operatorname{dom}(\bot)=(A\times A) \\ \operatorname{cod}(\bot)\subseteq A \end{cases} $, namely $\bot $ is function from $(A\times A) $ to $A $ (binary operation on $A$)

> **Question to proof**: $$(A, \bot) \text{ is Magma}\to \forall x,y \in A:\big ((x \bot y) \in A\big ) $$
>
> **Proof**: let be $x,y\in A$ and $(x,y)$, naturally $(x,y) \in (A \times A)$. But $(A \times A)=\operatorname{dom}(\bot) $ therefore $\exists z :\bigg (\big ((x,y),z\big ) \in \bot \bigg)$ with $\bot\subseteq \big(\operatorname{dom}(\bot)\times \operatorname{cod}(\bot)\big)$, [it means](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113296/operatornamefuncf-tox-y-in-f-to-fx-y-and-operatornamefuncf-t) $(x \bot y):=\bot \big ((x,y)\big )=z \in \operatorname{cod}(\bot)$, but $\operatorname{cod}(\bot) \subseteq A $ by def. von $ \bot $, therefore $(x \bot y)\in A$

Is it correct?

Comment: Proof of what statement?

Comment: Pardon, I edited...

Comment: A simple definition of magma: a set with a binary operation. Apart from notation, this means what you want to prove is immediate from the definition of a binary operation.

Comment: From https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/magma I read "A magma (binary algebraic structure) is a set equipped with a binary operation on it"... and not what I want to prove! But ok, wiki uses another def..

Comment: But that *is* what you want to prove. Given $x,y \in A$ where $R$ denotes the binary operation on $A$, then $xRy \in A.$ To make this like your statement change the symbol $R$ to the upside down T.

Comment: Pardon, I don't understand  your question... therefore I proved correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53157/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-mle).